# Executar Service com um BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android

Preciso executar um `Service` através de um `BroadcastReceiver`, mas ocorre o erro: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Para "desviar" do erro, estou usando o código abaixo, mas quero fazer da forma correta.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Preciso criar uma `IntentService` para isso ou há outras formas ?

Comment: Esse erro dá quando vc tenta fazer uma requisição na main thread. Muito provavelmente, quando o Broadcast receiver recebe um evento, vc ta executanddo sua função(que ta dentro do service?) na main thread.
Tenta colocar sua requisição, seja lá aonde ela estiver, numa thread separada.

Comment: Estou executando um Service dentro de um BroadcastReceiver. Mesmo assim seria a Main ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação:

> Atenção: Um serviço é executado no encadeamento principal em seu
>   processo de hospedagem — o serviço não cria seu próprio encadeamento e
>   não é executado em um processo separado (salvo se especificado). Isso
>   significa que, se o serviço for realizar qualquer trabalho intensivo
>   de CPU ou operações de bloqueio (como reprodução de MP3 ou rede), você
>   deve criar um novo encadeamento dentro do serviço. Usando um
>   encadeamento separado, você reduzirá o risco da ocorrência de erros de
>   Aplicativo não respondendo (ANR) e o encadeamento principal do
>   aplicativo poderá permanecer dedicado à interação do usuário com as
>   atividades.

Em inglês:

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the
>   service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate
>   process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your
>   service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations
>   (such as MP3 playback or networking), you should create a new thread
>   within the service to do that work. By using a separate thread, you
>   will reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors and
>   the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction
>   with your activities.

Ou seja, você está tentando fazer uma requisição na thread principal, por isso ocorre a exceção.

Fazer a requisição numa thread separada deve resolver o seu problema.

Pra fazer a requisição numa thread separada existem várias formas.
A mais simples é:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
    List<User> users = getUsersFromWebservice();
  }
});
thread.start();
```

Tem a AsyncTask, a minha preferida quando não estou usando o Retrofit.

```
class UserAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<User>>{
    protected void onPreExecute (){
        super.onPreExecute();

        /*
        Aqui é a hora pra você fazer tudo antes da requisição começar
        Ex: Alterar visibilidade de algumas view, avisar usuário e etc.
        */
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void...arg0) {
        //Aqui você faz a requisição.
        return getUsersFromWebservice();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<User> users) {
        super.onPostExecute(users);
        //Aqui você tem acesso ao retorno da  doInBackground(Void...arg0)
    }
}
```

Porém, existe uma lib chamada [Retrofit](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html). Ela, além de fazer a requisição, gerência todo esse processo de threading pra você.
Também tem a lib [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html), mas ela não faz toda a gerência da requisição com threads igual o Retrofit faz, você que vai ter que fazer utilizando qualquer um dos dois exemplos acima.

Comment: Max, poderia me dar um exemplo de uma requisição em thread separada ?

Answer (score 0):

Com o serviço sendo executado e já criando a nota `Thread`:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                // Aqui seu conteúdo para execução

            }
        };

        Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
        t.start();
        return Service.START_STICKY;

}
```